# Почему прямой запрос на сайт работает, а PHP запрос выдает ошибку?

Tags: php, json

Я делаю запрос на сервер с `API` и сразу получаю ответ. 
[Ссылка](http://185.47.152.162:82/prozone/gifts?session_id=1875c1e1642dcd03274b606f46343370) 
Если же я выполняю такой код на `PHP`, то приходит ошибка. В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

```php
$url = 'http://185.47.152.162:82/prozone/gifts?session_id=1875c1e1642dcd03274b606f46343370';

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

echo '<pre>'.print_r($data).'</pre>';
```

Ошибка

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://185.47.152.162:82/prozone/gifts?session_id=1875c1e1642dcd03274b606f46343370): failed to open stream: Connection timed out

Comment: попробуй использовать `curl`

Comment: @webDev_, file_get_contents() позволяет настроить заголовки запроса ;)

Comment: @webDev_, я пробовал cURL и JsonParse для JS(мало ли проблема в IP). Все равно выдавало ошибку.

Comment: @erm, а я сейчас для проверки взял ваш код из вопроса и выполнил его с localhost. Вернулись данные, без всяких ошибок. Возможно вас заблокировали на сервисе. Может у вас порты заблокированы на php. Может доступ функции к внешним ресурсам закрыт.

Comment: @Visman, доступ не закрыт(потому что API других сайтов получаю). На сервисе не заблокирован. А что с портами? Как их проверить? И как настроить?

Comment: Если вы аналогично работаете с другими api, то с портами у вас все в порядке.

Comment: @Visman, может быть запрет на обращение по IP, только по домену? Потому что все API, которые имеют домен работают отлично, а этот ну никак не хочет у меня работать.

Comment: API использует нестандартный порт 82, возможно закрыт как раз он (точнее открыты только 80, 433 например). Постучитесь по этому адресу и порту телнетом со своего хоста

Comment: @rjhdby, почему тогда прямой запрос проходит?

Comment: @erm потому, что прямой запрос вы запускаете из своего браузера

Comment: @rjhdby, я пытался использовать JS, который по идее использует мой же IP, и он тоже выдавал ошибку

Comment: @elm вы проверили телнетом доступность порта? Если да, то можно думать дальше, если нет, то можно долго спорить без какого либо результата

Comment: @rjhdby, я использовал этот код сократив его https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684327/how-to-execute-a-command-telnet-php и в итоге получил такую ошибку fsockopen(): unable to connect to 185.47.152.162:82 (Connection timed out). Видимо он недоступен